# Is there tool to install/fix Windows efi boot in /boot/efi from/on linux

Tags: windows, uefi

Is there Linux tool and done on Linux, or just definitive lines of shell codes or commands, to install/fix Windows efi boot in /boot/efi as ESP

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: what issue are you  trying to resolve?